# Number Guessing Game Python: Too many print statements in while loop when if statement condition is met

Tags: python

So, my issue is: When the condition of the if statement in the function is met, say "you lose" for 0 lives or "you won" for guessing the correct number, then it prints this as many times as guesses were made, aka

```
"You won."
"You won."
"You won."
```

when two wrong guesses were made and then the correct number is guessed. Does anyone know how to fix this issue, so that either statement, lose or win, is only print once? I feel like I either have to indent things differently, put it outside the function somehow or rewrite the if statements, but I've tried it out for a while with no success, so here I am.

```
from art import logo
import random 
from replit import clear

guess_number = random.choice(range(1, 101))
  
print(f"This is a cheat! Number is: {guess_number}")
print(logo)
print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!")
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100...Can you guess it?")

game_difficulty = input("Chooce a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard': ")
lives = 0
if game_difficulty == "easy":
  lives = 10
  print(f"You have {lives} attempts remaining to guess the number")
  user_guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
elif game_difficulty == "hard": 
  lives = 5
  print(f"You have {lives} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
  user_guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))



def guess_the_number():
  game_over = False
  global user_guess
  global guess_number
  global lives
  while not game_over:
    if user_guess == guess_number:
      game_over = True
      print("You won!")
      
    if user_guess != guess_number and lives == 0:
      game_over = True     
      print("You've run out of guesses, you lose.")

    
    elif user_guess != guess_number and lives != 0:
      lives -= 1
      if user_guess < guess_number and lives > 0:
        print("Too low.")
        print("Guess again.")
        print(f"You have {lives} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
        user_guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
        guess_the_number()
      elif user_guess > guess_number and lives > 0:
        print("Too high.")
        print("Guess again.")
        print(f"You have {lives} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
        user_guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
        guess_the_number()

        
guess_the_number()
```

Comment: You don't need the `user_guess != guess_number` condition, since the first `if` condition handles that.

Comment: Don't call the function recursively. The `while` loop takes care of repeating.

Comment: It finally runs without problems, thank you so much!